# Как найти путь src картинки по числу в data

Tags: jquery

> Хочу расписать весь принцип работы просмотра изображений, который я на
>   половину смог сделать.

Есть у меня 6 изображений!

```
<img src="myImages_1.jpeg" class="old-block" data-item="1"/>
<img src="myImages_2.jpeg" class="old-block" data-item="2"/>
<img src="myImages_3.jpeg" class="old-block" data-item="3"/>
<img src="myImages_4.jpeg" class="old-block" data-item="4"/>
<img src="myImages_5.jpeg" class="old-block" data-item="5"/>
<img src="myImages_6.jpeg" class="old-block" data-item="6"/>
```

Еще есть `<div>` в котором есть `img` - это нужно для preview просмотра изображения

```
<div>
 <img src="" data-item="" class="elemberg"/>
</div>
```

Дальше дублируется изображение при клике на класс `old-block`

```
$(".old-block").click(function () { //клик по классу old-block
        var src1 = $(this).attr('src'); //в переменную src1 получаю путь картинки
        $('.elemberg').attr('src', src1); //вставляю путь картинки в src c переменной src1 

        var src2 = $(this).attr('data-item');//копирую число с data-item
        $('.elemberg').attr('data-item', src2);//вставляю число в data-item 
});
```

У меня есть `<div>` в котором есть `img` - это нужно для полного просмотра изображения

> В этом блоке я листаю изображения это то что я не смог
>   реализовать

```
<div>
 <img src="" data-item="" class="elemberg zoom"/>
</div>

<div id="blockMainText_blockControlPanelBig_leftMain">Left</div>
<div id="blockMainText_blockControlPanelBig_rightMain">Right</div>
```

Дальше пытаюсь сделать чтобы можно было пролистать изображение в право

```
$('#blockMainText_blockControlPanelBig_leftMain').click(function(){
var data_item = $('.zoom').attr('data-item');//получаю число с data-item
 data_item++; // должно увеличивать моё полученное число на 1(-ну) еденицу
// тут продолжение кода
});
```

Дальше я застрял на пролистывании изображении.

> В задумке у меня было получить число с `data-item` и по этому число
>   найти путь изображения с атрибута `src`

Например:

> Есть у меня

```
<img src="" data-item="" class="elemberg zoom"/>
```

> при клике на кнопку и зная число `data-item например 3`, я получаю следующее

```
<img src="myImages_3.jpeg" class="elemberg zoom" data-item="3"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Номер надо запоминать вне клика. А дальше идет обычный слайдер...

```
var data_item;
$('#blockMainText_blockControlPanelBig_rightMain').click(function(){     
 var blocks = $('.old-block').length; 
 data_item = ( $('.zoom').attr('data-item') == blocks ) ? 1 : (data_item + 1); // (*1)

 var src = $('.old-block').eq( data_item ).attr('src'); // src картинки по номеру, .eq(...)
 $('.zoom').attr('src', src);
});
```

По строчке (*1)... это [Тернарный Оператор](http://learn.javascript.ru/ifelse) то же самое, что

```
if( $('.zoom').attr('data-item') == blocks ) {
  data_item = 1; 
} else {
  data_item = (data_item + 1);
}
```

Если номер равен количеству картинок - то ему уже некуда расти, превращается в 1. А если нет - увеличивается на 1. По слайду налево будет та же история, только если номер равен 1 - станет = кол-ву картинок... если нет, уменьшится на 1.

Но вообще говоря, если картинки у вас не будут хитро переставляться и data-item в этом не играет ключевой роли, то их вообще можно было убрать и оперировать индексами классов...

Comment: Единственное что не понятно это переменная `data_item`, в коде прописано чтобы она увеличивалась на единицу - а это присваивание переменной какое то значение! В моём случаи это не сработало! и пришлось ей присвоить значение! `data_item = 1`. И еще интересно что когда `data_item == blocks` `data_item` получает значение `1`, но изображение показывает по счёту 2 -е, главное массив состоит из 6 элементов а изображения показываются с 0 по 5 ( у нас 6 картинок ), мне еще пришлось уменьшить массив на 1 единицу! и `data_item` присвоить  `0`. Спасибо ваш пример мне помог с задачей.

Comment: `data_item =  data_item + 1;` — Это и есть увеличение на единицу. Делает ровно то же самое, что и `data_item++` просто, оно не может так увеличиваться бесконечно - а должно возвращаться к первой картинке, когда дойдя до последней, опять кликнут "next" ) А в JavaScript везде счет начинается с нуля, тогда как даты ваших картинок начинаются с 1. Для новичков очень непривычно)

Comment: data_item = data_item + 1; - у меня он работал но иногда присваивал к числу 1, например data_item = 1;   и когда срабатывает число превращалось в десятичное число в 11 а если еще раз нажать то 111 и так далее. На счёт нуля было не понятно единственное что счетчик показывал в массиве 6 элементов а на самом деле их 5 - это если брать в учёт что счёт начинается с 0. Для меня это загадка) поетому и пришлось количество массива уменьшить на 1.

Comment: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 = всего шесть штук) А число из attr('data...') получается в виде строки (о чем я благополучно забыл). В том плане, что `4 + '5' = 45` такая проблема есть только с суммированием. Чтобы избавится от неё - ставят плюсик перед строкой, и она превращается в число. `4 + +'5' = 9`

Comment: Так что то меня понесло не в ту степь, Спасибо за помощь :)

Answer (score 0):

Код использую пользователя [OPTIMUS PRIME](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/310962/optimus-prime).

```
var countImages = $('.old-block').length; // узнаем количество элементов + глобальная переменная
var data_items = 0; // счётчик  + глобальная переменная

function rightButtonViewImages(){ // функция, так как обращаюсь к данной функции через кнопки клавиатуры, чтобы не дублировать код сделал функцию
    if( $('.zoom').attr('data-item') == countImages ) { // проверяем,если data-item равен количеству элементов countImages то
        data_items = 0; // наше число обнуляем
        $('.elemberg').attr('data-item', data_items); // устанавливаем число в data_item с переменной data_items 
    } else { // или
        data_items++; //увеличиваем переменную на 1 единицу
        $('.elemberg').attr('data-item', data_items);// устанавливаем число в data_item с переменной data_items 
    }
    var src = $('.old-block').eq(data_items).attr('src'); // тут присваиваем путь переменной src. Ищем data-item у которого есть значение и ищет его у элементов у которых есть класс .old-block и data-item равно нашему значению и берет наш путь картинки
    $('.elemberg').attr('src', src);//устанавливаем путь картинки
    $('.elemberg').attr('data-item', data_items);// устанавливаем число в data_item с переменной data_items 

}
```

> Дальше я добавил возможность листать изображение при клике на кнопку в
>   право!

```
$('html').keydown(function(eventObject){
    if (event.keyCode == 39) { // 39 это номер клавиши в право
        if ($("#mainBlockForViewImages").hasClass("selected")) { // проверяю есть ли класс у моего элемента
            rightButtonViewImages(); // вызываю функцию, что бы изображение пролистывалось!
        }
    }
});
```

На этом [сайте](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B8_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88) указанны все номера клавиш.

> 27 - кнопка <kbd>Esc</kbd>
>
> 37 - кнопка влево (стрелки) <kbd><</kbd>
>
> 39 - кнопка вправо (стрелки)<kbd>></kbd>
>
> 107 - кнопка <kbd>NumPad +</kbd>
>
> 109 - кнопка <kbd>NumPad -</kbd>

Comment: Замечу, что в таком случае `data-items="..."` вообще может не участвовать) Нужный номер и так сохраняется в переменной `var data_items` — оттуда и можно каждый раз доставать нужное число для `eq()` - и не запариваться над датами из HTML)

Comment: data-items я через него просматривал счетчик, так как было что картинка не по счёту открывалась. Таким способом я проверял какое изображение по счёту открывается как при нажатии в право и в лево)

Comment: В смысле, так - https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/6cqmfr5x/ )